# i have this error when i want tu use model binding in laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

## RouteServiceProvider

```
public function boot(Router $router)
    {
        parent::boot($router);

        $router->model('article','App\article');
    }
```

## web.php

```
Route::resource('article','articleController');
```

## controller

```
public function show(Article $article)
    {

        /*$article=Article::find($id);*/

        if(!$article){

            abort(404);

        }

        return view('article.show ',compact('article'));
```

> Declaration of App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::boot(App\Providers\Router $router) should be compatible with Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::boot()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue comes from PHP inheritance. When you override a method, you have to keep the same signature than the parent method (except for `__construct`). The `boot` method of Laravel service provider is called through the container, so you can use Dependency Injection, but not in this case because `App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider` inherits from another service provider which already has a `boot` method defined.
In your case, you need to remove the Router from the signature and retrieve it from the method content thanks to

```php
$router = $this->app['router'];
```

Comment: I am new in laravel .What should i do now

Comment: how specify controller(aticleControler)

Comment: `$router->get('/user', 'UserController@index');` for example